# Spring Form Ajax Request + Hibernate Validation

Tags: ajax, hibernate, spring, spring-3, hibernate-validator

I always used `@Valid` and a `BindingResult` to validate form fields.
Now using Ajax, based on [this](http://blog.springsource.org/2010/01/25/ajax-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/) article, it's not possible to use `BindingResult` instead of or additional to `HttpServletResponse` because this would result in a Bad Request (HTTP Error Code 400).

How to validate my form fields now?

```
  @RequestMapping( value = "/save.html", params = "json", method = RequestMethod.POST )
  public @ResponseBody Map<String, ? extends Object> saveJSON( @RequestBody Location location, /* BindingResult result, */ HttpServletResponse response )
  {
    return Collections.singletonMap( "foo", "foobar" );
  }
```

This was the old way without ajax:

```
  @RequestMapping( value = "/save.html", method = RequestMethod.POST )
  public String save( @ModelAttribute( "location" ) @Valid Location location, BindingResult result, Map<String, Object> map )
  {
    Location l;
    if ( ( l = service.findByTitle( location.getTitle() ) ) != null )
    {
      if ( location.getId() != l.getId() )
      {
        result.addError( new FieldError( "location", "title", messageSource.getMessage( "Unique.location.title", null, null ) ) );
      }
    }

    if ( result.hasErrors() )
    {
      return "locationform";
    }

    service.save( location );
    return "redirect:/locations/index.html";
  }
```

**EDIT**

Tried this, but there's no `errors` member in result which contains `true` when leaving form unfilled (this should cause a @NotEmpty Constraint message)

```
  @RequestMapping( value = "/save.html", params = "json", method = RequestMethod.POST )
  public @ResponseBody Map<String, ? extends Object> saveJSON( @RequestBody Location location, HttpServletResponse response, Map<String, Object> map )
  {
    BindingResult result = new BeanPropertyBindingResult( location, "" );
    if ( result.hasErrors() ) map.put( "errors", true );
    map.put( "foo", "foobar" );
    return map;
  }
```

Comment: Which version of spring do you use 3.0 or 3.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are using hibernate validator. If so try this

in your **Controller** :

```
//other imports
import javax.validation.Validator;
@Controller()
class MyController{

    @autowire()
    @qualifier("myValidator")
    private Validator validator;
    public Validator getValidator() {
        return mValidator;
    }

    public void setValidator(Validator validator) {
        this.mValidator = validator;
    }

   @RequestMapping( value = "/save.html", params = "json", method = RequestMethod.POST )
   public @ResponseBody Map<String, ? extends Object> saveJSON( @RequestBody Location location, HttpServletResponse response )
   {
       Set<ConstraintViolation<Location>> errors = getValidator().validate(location);
       Map<String, String> validationMessages = new HashMap<String, String>();
       if(!errors.isEmpty())
       {
          //this map will contain the validation messages
          validationMessages = validationMessages(errors); 

          //probably you would like to send the errors back to client
          return validationMessages ;
       }
       else
       {
           //do whatever you like to do with the valid bean

       }
   }

   public Map<String, String> validationMessages(Set<ConstraintViolation<Location>> failures) {
        Map<String, String> failureMessages = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for (ConstraintViolation<Location> failure : failures) {

                failureMessages.put(failure.getPropertyPath().toString(), failure.getMessage());
        }
        return failureMessages;
    }



}
```

in your **spring context** file add the following bean

```
<beans:bean id="myValidator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" />
```

hope it helps :)